# How do I two-way sync an iPhone with a Mac?

Tags: itunes, iphone, sync

My iPhone was synced to my MacBook Pro when I first got it. Since then I have put a lot of info on my iPhone.

I want to sync the iPhone with the Mac and merge the two rather than have the Mac replace all the info on the iPhone. Can this be done? I do not know the initial setting when the first sync occurred. Is there a way to determine the setting without connecting the two?

Comment: I always thought that by syncing the iPhone, it was a merge. It doesn't erase any information on either device.

Answer (score 1):

Select your iPhone under the devices list in iTunes, then select the info tab at the top. This will give you you the ability to 'merge' your contacts, calendar, and mail with options at the bottom to do a one way sync from your Mac to your iPhone (Make sure these are not checked if you want to 'merge'). As far as photos and movies you can import these into iPhoto. Third party apps are backed up automatically. Is there any other data you were thinking of merging?

Answer (score 1):

Syncing with the same Macbook will Merely merge the two information pools (iPhone and Mac)

Thats the point of 'Syncing' It ensures both devices have the **same** data

Answer (score 0):

You can also use third-party software for that: Senuti (iTunes spelled backwards) or DeTune for Mac.

For windows, there is a nice forum thread here:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1189743

Comment: This should not have been downvoted because it's still a good answer